# Weird characters in Scene Builder

Tags: intellij-idea, scenebuilder

Complete novice here. I'm just getting started with programming (going for my bachelor's). I'm having some weird issue with Scene Builder displaying weird/odd characters in place of what should be component names. I'm running macOS (Big Sur) with IntelliJ and Scene Builder integrated. [Screenshot of weird characters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KzxOQ.jpg)

IntelliJ Version: 2021.2.1

Scene Builder Version: 16.0.0

Is there a bug or do I have something configured incorrectly? Any help is super appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

It's a bug, see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-266524

As a workaround, please try to download the standalone Scene Builder version and use it: https://gluonhq.com/products/scene-builder/

Comment: I figured it was something like that. Thanks a million, Konstantin. I appreciate it.